# Customize itemize environment for cv

Tags: itemize, indexing, cv

I'm updating my CV and i want to create a "custom itemize" that looks like an index. More or less like this but I want a "dotted line" between "problem session" and 15h.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possibility with `tabularx` and `listliketab`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, german]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularx, listliketab}
\let\tabitem\textbullet

\begin{document}

\storestyleof{itemize}
\begin{listliketab}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}LX<{\,\dotfill}@{}>{\dotfill\,}r@{}}
 \tabitem & \underline{Àlgebra lineal} Grau en Matemàtiques, problem session & 15h.\\
 \tabitem & \underline{Topologia} Seminar session & 12h 30.
   \end{tabularx}
\end{listliketab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't find how to automatize it but writing:

```
    \item \underline{Àlgebra lineal} Grau en Matemàtiques, problem session\dotfill 15h.
    \item \underline{Topologia} Seminar session, \dotfill 12h.
```

It's works.